# Wordpress additional login rules

Tags: wordpress, validation, authentication

I made a plugin that requires the user to validate their email address. It creates "activation_key" meta key with random string for the user and sets it to '' once the user validates. So far so good. But now I need to hook into login and check that activation_key == ''.

This is what I thought should be, but it doesn't get to here.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'check_if_activated', 10, 3 );
function check_if_activated($user, $username, $password)
{
    // check if user has activated their email

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress already adds filters to `authenticate`, so you have to register your lower.

```php
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'check_if_activated', 50);
function check_if_activated($user)
{
    // If we have an error, no need to check the activation key
    // (Wrong credentials, for instance)
    if (is_wp_error($user))
    {
        return $user;
    }
    // Checks the meta and returns an error if needed
    $validation_key = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'activation_key', true);
    return empty($validation_key) ? $user : new WP_Error('your_plugin_error_code', 'your error message');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it's job, BUT it only works if it's in functions.php, and not in the plugin. The add_filter is in constructor and a public method... Also, what exactly do the third and fourth parameter do in add_filter?

Comment: The third and fourth parameters are the priority of your filter and the number of arguments you want to retrieve in your callback.
More details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter